# Install Russian on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, language, input-languages, language-pack

Is this possible? I need a keyboard layout for Russian and Ukranian - but it's not in the Regional Language and Settings list and I have enabled the advanced languages as well. I've tried Windows Updates, tried downloading MUI's to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In Control panel, go to **Regional and Language Options**

Under the *Languages* Tab, click *Details*

On the Settings screen, click *Add...*

On the input language, select either:

- **Russian**, then you can select *Russian* or *Russian (Typewriter)*, or
- **Ukranian**, where you only have *Ukrainian* as the keyboard layout.

[image: control panel steps]

to add all languages back into the list, you will need [this](http://wikisend.com/download/236484/INTL.INF) INF file, and your XP install disk.

[INF is a text file, so you can view it first if you want to check it out - it **should** be the same as your XP install disk]

replace the INTL.INF that is currently in c:\Windows\inf, then reboot the computer. This should restore access to all the languages.

Comment: Russian and Ukranian do not exist under the Input Language Options, that's the problem.

Comment: added info on restoring missing languages

Comment: C:\Windows\Inf does not exist

Comment: the **INF** folder is hidden. you will need to enable view of hidden system folders, or when you are in your windows folder, go to the address bar, and type `\INF` after the c:\windows folder

Comment: Okay - but when does it actually copy the stuff over from the CD? Since I have tried to right click install with the CD in the drive and it does nothing

Comment: Hi Sean, I have tried this, after reboot, the languages are still not there :(

Comment: you copied the INF file you downloaded over the one in c:\windows\inf ?

Comment: Yes, then rebooted with CD in the drive, and nothing has happened